# how to merge more than 2 dictionaries in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary, merge

Trying to merge two or more dictionaries in python 2.7, However

****kwargs** is not supported in python 2.7 it gives error like-Python version 2.7 does not support starred expressions in dicts .

is there any way to do it in python 2.7 ?

```
# Create first dictionary
dict1 = {  'Ritika': 5, 'Sam': 7, 'John' : 10 }
# Create second dictionary
dict2 = {'Aadi': 8,'Sam': 20,'Mark' : 11 }
# Create second dictionary
dict3 = {'x': 8,'y': 20,'z' : 11 }

dict4 = {**dict1 , **dict2, **dict3}
print dict4
```

Expected output-

```
{'Ritika': 5, 'Sam': 20, 'John': 10, 'Aadi': 8, 'Mark': 11, 'x': 8, 'y': 20, 'z': 11}
```

Comment: Did you try this solution? with the copy?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression-taking-union-of-dictiona

Comment: @programandoconro, dictionaries cannot have duplicate keys. The last ```"sam"``` key is the one which has the value as 20. So ```"sam":20``` is taken

Comment: Given the solution for 2 dictionaries in the linked duplicate, it is enough to do: `merge_two_dicts(merge_two_dicts(x, y), z)`.

Comment: yes i tried it is working for only two dictionary @Shai

Comment: ignore duplicates no issues @Sujay

Comment: sorry i did't get you @sophros

Comment: Go check the [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26853961/6573902) to the linked question and use `mrge_two_dicts` from there.

Comment: I have tried that however it is working for only two dicts i want to do it for 3-4 dicts. @sophros  I am able to do it in python 3 . but my question is for python 2.7.

Comment: It might sound stupid, but @sophros is kind of right in his way of "merge_two_dicts(merge_two_dicts(x, y), z)".
What might help you is merge_many_dicts(myArrayOfDicts)
Send an array of your dictionaries into this fuction and inside the function Iterate over them and insert them into a new dictionary with the copy() and update.
This will create a totally new dictionary but it combines all of them